# $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\cos (\sinh x)- \cosh(\sin x)}{(e^{\sqrt{x}}-5^{\sqrt{x}})^4}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to solve the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\cos (\sinh x)- \cosh(\sin x)}{(e^{\sqrt{x}}-5^{\sqrt{x}})^4}$$

Applying Taylor's series.

$$\cos(\sinh x)=1- \frac{x^2}{2}+ o(x^2)$$

$$\cosh(\sin x)=1+ \frac{x^2}{2}+ o(x^2)$$

but I don't know how to treat the denominator because the derivatives are not defined in $0$.
Can someone please give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:
Use equivalence of functions:

\begin{align}
\mathrm e^{\sqrt x}-5^{\sqrt x}&=\mathrm e^{\sqrt x}-\mathrm e^{\ln 5\sqrt x}=1+\sqrt x+o\bigl(\sqrt x\bigr)-1-\ln5\sqrt x+o\bigl(\sqrt x\bigr)\cr
&=(1-\ln 5)\sqrt x+o\bigl(\sqrt x\bigr)\sim_0(1-\ln 5)\sqrt x.
\end{align}
and therefore $\;\bigl(\mathrm e^{\sqrt x}-5^{\sqrt x}\bigr)^4\sim_0 (1-\ln 5)^4x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the denominator also as follows by writing

$$\frac{\cos (\sinh x)- \cosh(\sin x)}{(e^{\sqrt{x}}-5^{\sqrt{x}})^4} = \frac{x^2}{(e^{\sqrt{x}}-5^{\sqrt{x}})^4}\cdot \frac{\cos (\sinh x)- \cosh(\sin x)}{x^2}$$

Now, you can handle the first fraction by substituting $x=t^2$
\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{x^2}{(e^{\sqrt{x}}-5^{\sqrt{x}})^4}
& \stackrel{x=t^2}{=} & \frac{t^4}{(e^{t}-5^{t})^4} \\
& = & \left(\frac{t}{e^{t}-5^{t}}\right)^4 \\
& \stackrel{t\to 0}{\longrightarrow} & \frac 1{(1-\ln 5)^4}
\end{eqnarray*}

You can handle the second fraction by your already found Taylor series to get

$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\cos (\sinh x)- \cosh(\sin x)}{x^2}=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Try to graph the function (you can use the trigonometric functions or the Taylor series as such) so that you can find the limit by approaching from the right (i.e. $0^+$).